# Hosting and streaming video to an ios app

Tags: ios, video, stream

I am about to build an app that initially displays thumbnails of high quality videos. When  users click on a thumbnail, they will go through iOS's in-app payment system to pay for the video and once that is complete, the video will open and start playing in Quicktime(iphones native video player).
Can you please suggest where i should host my videos? Does apple provide video uploads as well or is there a simple to use tool that allows this? I am looking for a service that will let me upload or delete high quality videos whenever needed so that non tech people can administer too. Then i can easily just link those videos to my app.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Depends on format if its just progressive download mp4 you could contract with any of the hosting companies, they start at 5.00 - 100 dollars monthly depending on what you need. the higher priced ones offer dedicated servers that can run .net or php, you could take a service for instance that hosts at 5.00 a month,, right a simple php app that does the security or get a pre-built one.

If you want to do real streaming using HLS then you need a server that can support it, one though a bit expensive is wowzma, prices vary but it is usually quite expensive.